# Save an Image into a dynamically created directory in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, directory, qimage, qlabel

I am a beginner in Qt. I want to save a cropped image when clicking the button "save" :

[image: This is the application I am developing, image label containing a cropped image which is to be saved]]

I have to create a directory at the run time, name of the directory should be the text in the textEdit field near the "id" label and the name of the saved image file name should be the text in the textEdit field near the "name" label.

I stored those values to  strings

```
QString id=ui->ids->toPlainText();

 QString names=ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
```

in on_saveButton_clicked event I have given the lines as

```
border2.save("C:\Qtworks\imagecrop_Jubilee\\"+ id+ "\\" +names+ ".jpg");
```

[border2 is the QImage containg the cropped image]

But no image is being saved...

please help me to solve this..

Comment: [QDir::mkpath](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html) would probably help.

Comment: Btw, in Qt, you can always use `/` as path separator. No need to mess with escaping backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the path to the file correctly. Instead of `"C:\Qtworks\...` you should use `C:\\Qtworks\\...` or `C:/Qtworks/...`.

That's because the compiler uses `\` as an escape character in strings (for things like `\t`, `\n` or `\r`). so `\\` is actually turned into `\`.

Also you should create the directory before saving the file :

```
QDir dir;
dir.mkdir("C:/Qtworks/imagecrop_Jubilee/"+ id);
```

Comment: Thanks, The image is getting saved simply in the working directory "C:/Qtworks/imagecrop_Jubilee/" But i want to create a folder in that named id and to save the image in that folder it is not working, I have given the code as ' border2.save("C:/Qtworks/imagecrop_Jubilee/"+ id+ "/" + names+ ".jpg");'

Comment: You should use `QDir::mkpath` to create the directory. See the updated answer.